# How can I set a unique cookie for each page?

Tags: php, cookies

I have a button on my site. When a user clicks on it
it sets a cookie like this:

```
setcookie("check",$id, mktime (0, 0, 0, 12, 31, 2015));
```

But when the user goes to other pages and clicks on the button again the cookie for old page is getting replaced by the new page.

How can I set a unique cookie for each page?
I am using PHP.
I tried:

```
setcookie("$id",$id, mktime (0, 0, 0, 12, 31, 2015));
```

but it didn't work.
How can I give it a unique name each time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the 4th parameter, *path*.

```
setcookie("check",$id, mktime (0, 0, 0, 12, 31, 2015), "/mypath/mypage.php");
```

See this reference: http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php

You should also consider setting the 5th parameter, *domain*:

```
setcookie("check",$id, mktime (0, 0, 0, 12, 31, 2015), "/mypath/mypage.php", ".mysite.com");
```

Comment: Or label each cookie by the pagename

Comment: Yes, that would work unless you need more than one cookie per page.

Comment: @JonathanM "check".$page and "check2".$page - this is if you needed to access the cookies anywhere, of course.

Comment: @BadalSurana, no problem. Check out Col. Shrapnel's answer also. If you have a lot of data to store, his answer addresses server-side session persistent data.

Answer (score 5):

This is very clumsy way, not to mention that the cookies are limited to 20 per domain.

You have to set up only one cookie, an unique user identifier.
And store all other data related to that user on the server side.